# Bamboo Mailer & SES Failing to send an email to one specific user

Tags: erlang, elixir, amazon-ses

I am working on a production server that sends roughly 1000 emails a day with almost no issues. There is a single email that always fails and I have been unable to send an email to this user through our system. The site is built with Elixir and uses the Bamboo Mailer, specifically the `smtp_adapter` but I believe this may be an issue with SES rather than our code or the Elixir libraries we are using.

The particular user always throws this error:

```
{{:nocatch, {:permanent_failure, "501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided\r\n"}},
```

From what I can tell the email address is valid and the customer has verified it as such and stated that emails have been sent and received to the user outside of our system.

I'm looking for some context on how SES determines what a valid RCPT TO address is and more generally how SES works to send emails. I haven't been able to find much on this issue from the SES docs.

Comment: This might be difficult to troubleshoot without knowing the problematic email, but that's definitely not something that you should share.

Comment: For sure haha. I've run the address through some validators and the customer has confirmed that it works. It's nothing crazy, pretty generic, standard, corporate email address.

Comment: Are there other email addresses that use the same domain name?

Comment: @Everett I was unsure but today an order was placed by another customer, same domain and we got the same error.  Which, I suppose means there is a problem with the specific domain they are using... It's nothing fancy though.

Comment: That's useful info. If you can get your own email address at the same domain, it would be useful for debugging. I would try sending emails from various clients in different languages and see which ones are delivered successfully, then I would inspect the _entire_ message (headers and all) to see exactly which differences are present.  I would suspect something with a header, but without data, that's just a hunch.

Comment: Thanks @Everett, I imagine we will leave it there for a while, if they do end up giving me a throw away account I will post a resolution if/when I figure it out.